# How do I provide access to my k3s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k3s cluster (2 nodes) running a simple nginx service. I'm trying to expose that to the internet. I need to forward all traffic from my router to something in k3s in order to serve things on *.home.my.tld.

I'm unsure what the steps are to achieve this. I know k3s comes with traefik but it doesn't have an internal IP address to be able to forward all traffic to. My understanding is I can use treafik to then forward traffic to the correct service based on hostname. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), which will accept and route requests.